# Paint rectangle each time a method is called

Tags: java, swing

I'm having a problem in java where each time a method is called in the paint class, it updates the coordinates for the rectangle then should paint it.

At the moment, all I'm getting is the method updating the coordinates fine. But only one rectangle is displayed, which is the last one the method updates.

How can I then create a rectangle for each time the methods called, not just on the last iteration?

In my main class I have the following code which reads data from a file. It reads one line then calls the paint class to draw the rectangle before reading the next

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("numbers.txt"))) 
{
    String line;

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        int change2Int=Integer.parseInt(line.trim());
        mp.getDataForDisplay(change2Int);//send to paint class
    }
}
catch (Exception expe)
{
    expe.printStackTrace();
}
```

The file numbers.txt just houses:

```
0
3
5
2
```

The paint class has:

```
class mainPanel extends JPanel
{
    int processes, storedProcesses;

    // for rectangles
    int xCoor =0;
    int yCoor =0;
    int width =10;
    int height =50;

    static int x = 100;
    int [] y = {100,150,200,250,300,350,400,450,500,550};

//constructor and other irrelevant methods here
public void getDataForDisplay (int proc)
{
    //the method checks the value from "proc" to see where to display a rectangle on screen. Only prints last rectangle to screen
    int loop = 0;

    while (loop <= storedProcesses)
    {
        if (proc == loop)
        {
            xCoor =  x;
            yCoor = y[loop];
            x = x + 10;
            System.out.println("right");
            repaint();
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("wrong");
        }

        loop++;
    }

    System.out.println("OK WERE HERE");
    repaint();
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);   

    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillRect (xCoor, yCoor, width, height);
}
```

Comment: Please adhere to [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html).

Comment: What value does 'storeProc' store? Do 'while' and 'if' conditions accord with the value?

Comment: it reads from a textfile an INT as shown above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two common approaches

1. You need to keep a list of Rectangles to paint and iterate through the list every time.
2. Paint your Rectangle to a BufferedImage and paint the BufferedImage.

Check out [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for working examples of both of these approaches.

Comment: I'm more or less using the first point. I thought I was keeping a list?

Comment: @lecardo, `I thought I was keeping a list?` maybe your are, but your paintComponent() method doesn't iterate through the list. You specifically hardcode one painting statement so only one object will ever get painted. If you want multiple objects painted you need to iterate through the list. Look at the examples I provided.

Comment: Would it be possible if your able to give it a shot? I'm having no luck here =/

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what your code is doing. I gave you working examples that show how to add an Object to a List and then paint that object. I have no idea what you find confusing about my working examples. You need to restructure your code to something similar (not exact) to my example.